# Shell script to replace string and add new line

Tags: sed

I am new to shell scripting and have a request to modify multiple files. I have
   **the input as below**

```
#this is line1 for file1@abc.com        
test line 2  
test line 3  
this is line4 for file1@abc.com  
test line 5  
this is line6 for file1@abc.com
```

**and need output like**

```
#this is line1 for file1@abc.com   
test line 2  
test line 3   
##this is line4 for file1@abc.com  
this is line4 for file1@xyz.com  
test line 5   
##this is line6 for file1@abc.com**  
this is line6 for file1@xyz.com
```

i tried the below sed command, but not able to get the required output. It is not skipping the #line and appends it.

```
sed -e "/abc.com/{h;s/^/##/P;x;G; /^#/!s/abc.com/xyz.com/;}" file1
```

is there something i am missing???

Please help and any other suggestions would also be much appreciated.

Regards,
Santosh

Comment: Can you more clearly show what your desired output is? Are the `*` part of the input and part of the desired output? Nothing in your example sed command skips lines with leading `#` for the first bit of work.

Comment: Etan - Thanks that is what exactly i am not able to isolate

Comment: I have modified the input and output accordingly now

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be what you want

```
sed '/^[^#].*@abc.com/ {h; s/^/##/; p; g; s/abc.com/xyz.com/;}'
```

The equivalent awk:

```
awk '/^[^#].*abc.com/ {print "##" $0; sub(/abc.com/, "xyz.com")};1'
```

Pedantically, the dot should be escaped: `abc\.com`

Comment: i tried this command but it gives me error   sed: Function /^[^#].*@abc.com/ {h; s/^/##/; p; g; s/abc.com/xyz.com/} cannot be parsed.

Comment: Hmm, worked for me with GNU sed. Try adding a semicolon before the ending brace.

Comment: Thanks Glenn. It worked perfectly well after adding the semicolan

Comment: How to do case insensitive sed, i mean like how to replace ABC.com XYZ.com in the search

Comment: With GNU sed, you would use `s/.../.../i`, Otherwise you may have to `s/[aA][bB][cC]\.com/xyx.com/`

Comment: i tried this  sed '/^[^#].*@abc.com/ {h; s/^/##/; p; g; s/abc.com/xyz.com/i;}' but it is not working

Comment: then i tried sed '/^[^#].*@abc.com/ {h; s/^/##/; p; g; s/[aA][bB][cC]\.com/xyx.com/;}' that too didnt work

Comment: Why's that, because you have "ABC" and not "abc" in the text? Note that block of commands is only executed if `/^[^#].*@abc.com/` matches, so you have to make that part insensitive too.

Comment: ok i am totally lost here. i have to search for abc.com from a file which contains text like abc.com, ABC. com Abc.COM and need to replace it like xyz.com, XYZ.com Xyz.COM along with the above conditions. Please help

Comment: Let's take this out of a comment discussion: please ask a new question, and then @-mention me in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/^\([^#].*\)abc\.com/##&\n\1xyz.com/' file
```

Only substitute lines which do not begin with a `#` and containd `abc.com`. The RHS of the substitution consists of the original line prepended by `##` and a second line where the string `abc.com` is replace by `xyz.com`.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '
    /^#/n; 
    /.*abc.com/{
        h;  # hold this line to HOLD SPACE
        s/abc.com/xyz.com/;  # modify
        x;  # exchange PATTERN with HOLD
        s/^/##/;  
        G;  # get
    }
'
```